# how to open new page in existing page using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to open new page in place of existing page I use this

```
 window.open('EmployeeTraining.aspx?searchkey=' + $("[id$='txtSearchVotes']").val(), '_self', false);
```

but its not working

Any Idea Is I am using correct this code

Comment: any error you are getting in the console?

Comment: HTML1524: Invalid DOCTYPE. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.top.location = "url";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a new value to the `location` property.

`location = "new url"`

Comment: var url = 'EmployeeTraining.aspx?searchkey=' + $([id$='txtSearchVotes']").val();
                location = url

Comment: We have no way of telling how your case is different.

Comment: @Quentin whats the differnce between `location` and `locaiton.href`

Comment: @bhb — For the purposes of this question, nothing. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location) for a more in depth explanation.